# Apple: In App Purchase Subscriptions & Server to Server Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm having some trouble figuring out Apple's Server-To-Server Status Updates for In App Purchases:

For example– they say they provide these notifications:

```
CANCEL

DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_PREF

DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS

DID_FAIL_TO_RENEW

DID_RECOVER

INITIAL_BUY

INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL

RENEWAL
```

But for some reason, they do not provide the applicable transaction, but instead provide "the last 100 receipts". Here's the documentation– they also appear to be [deprecating the field](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/responsebody) that previously provided the single relevant object.

`latest_receipt_info array`

> An array that contains the latest 100 in-app
>   purchase transactions of the decoded value in latest_receipt. This
>   array excludes transactions for consumable products that your app has
>   marked as finished. The contents of this array are identical to those
>   in responseBody.Latest_receipt_info in the verifyReceipt endpoint
>   response for receipt validation.

If I receive a notification with a status– how can I correlate which of the last 100 receipts the notification is relevant to?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65265197/iosauto-renewable-in-app-purchase-server-to-server-notification-parsing-issue

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't rely on particular transaction. These notifications are not attached to a transaction, but to a subscription.
You should read more articles about validating App Store receipts and Apple Notifications.

Answer (score 1):

As Apple states in the deprecation hint, use the **unified_receipt** object to get `latest_receipt` and `latest_receipt_info`.

> Update any existing code to rely on the following objects in unified_receipt instead.

The [unified_receipt](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/unified_receipt) contains the deprecated top-level objects.

Comment: Yeah– but the latest_receipt_info is now an "array of the last 100 receipts" instead of the last receipt...

Comment: Ah, you're right. Never used it. As far as I can see it, the first entry is always the latest. To be sure, you could order all by the `expires_date`

Comment: @PaulSchröder can we add custom attributes on Server to Server Notifications ?

Comment: @guru you can't add attributes to the notifications from Apple's server. What would be an attribute you want to add?

Comment: i want to include user information like user id , user name

Comment: This isn't possible. Also where should this include happen? I assume such properties are something you would need to fetch from your server anyway, so you can do the determination of user id, name, ... on your server based on the receipt data when your server receives the server-to-server notification from Apple. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @PaulSchröder i agree with you that we can not send custom attributes in APNS server to server push, is there any official documentation from Apple?

Comment: @guru you mean an official documentation for server-to-server notifications?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65265197/iosauto-renewable-in-app-purchase-server-to-server-notification-parsing-issue

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is check the array `latest_receipt_info` and get the one with the latest `expiration_date`

Here you have 2 resources that can help you.

**Engineering Subscriptions 2018** =>
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/705/

**Transcript from the same conference** => https://www.wwdcnotes.com/notes/wwdc18/705/