# IOS:Auto renewable In App Purchase server to server notification parsing issue

Tags: in-app-purchase

I am unable to parse app store auto renewable purchase notification.I am only to get notification_type, but other fileds i am unable parse from server notification.
my php code:

```
<?php

$input =json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$responseBody = $input['unified_receipt']['latest_receipt_info'][0]->original_transaction_id;
$notification_type = $input['notification_type'];

$sql="INSERT INTO testAppServerNotification (notification_type,notification) VALUES('$notification_type','$responseBody')";
$result=$conn->query($sql);
if($result){
   echo "success";
 }else{
     error_log("fail" . $conn->error);
 }
?>
```

Comment: can anybody please share json format of app store sent notification?

Answer (score 1):

The boolean in `json_decode()` defines that json objects should be decoded as associative arrays instead of objects. Hence you access the `orignal_transaction_id` wrong.

You have to do it like this:

```
$responseBody = $input['unified_receipt']['latest_receipt_info'][0]["original_transaction_id"];
```

This way, you should be able to parse the notification.

If you want to learn more about the structure of server notifications, here is the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/responsebody) from Apple.